Wood grain direction
Very new to Blender and need some help with wood grain and exporting some files.
I have around 35 sample doors that I need a wood texture for that needs to be exported in glb/gltf format for a specific WordPress website plugin, Visody, that my employer is using (Mainly it's free and has the most features).
The doors are modeled in Fusion 360 and have exported them as FBX files so I don't need to select every single polygon to apply the material as there are 35+ doors and this would take forever.
(If there's a better way please let me know)
I am running into a problem where the direction of grain is changing whether or not the surface is curved or a separate surface.
In the example image I need the grain in the yellow section to be vertical but depending on the surface some are horizontal.
Any help is appreciated, Thanks!


You need to UV unwrap your and align all the faces to aim in the direction you want the grain to go. Probably would work ok if you just selected all of one "side" of the door (meaning inside or outside) in Edit Mode and press U > Unwrap to unwrap it all as one island. Then just rotate that to align with the grain of your wood texture. Then do the same to the other side or mirror it, whatever works for your needs.

I will give it a shot, thank you for your help
